# Can you change a mac address on a Chromebook using Linux beta? (mac spoofing)

Tags: mac-address, chromebook

I know there's a way to change your MAC address temporarily however I can't be bothered having to go to the store to buy a USB to back up my files so I can go into developer mode. So I was wondering, can you change your mac address with Linux beta using macchanger or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Linux Beta ([Crostini](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromiumos/docs/+/master/containers_and_vms.md#Can-I-run-a-different-Linux-distro)) runs in a Linux Container (on LXD) inside a virtual machine image (termina) on the Chromebook. Developers built it this way to contain malware, bad actors or misconfiguration inside the environment. Changing the MAC address of the host would bypass many layers of security, which would be a bug or worse if it's possible.

Also why are you going to enable developer mode when you have Linux Beta enabled and at the same time asking such questions? I know, I know, destroying your own data, building error prone products and services because "everyone" does it.